# HTML form not sending correct data, PHP pagination 

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

I have recently used a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) pagination tutorial, *[Pagination - what it is and how to do it](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html)*, to display record information from a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database. The problem is that the page only sends out the information sent in the latest form, and I am not quite sure how to fix the problem.

The code for the form output is shown below.

```
$musicitems = getmusicitems($pagenumber,$prevpage,$lastpage,$nextpage);
$count = ($musicitems==NULL) ? 0 : mysql_num_rows($musicitems);
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    $records = mysql_fetch_assoc($musicitems);
    print'
        <label for="deleteMusicItem'.$records['m_id'].'" id="deleteMusicItemLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Delete Music Record:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="deleteMusicItem"  id ="deleteMusicItem'.$records['m_id'].'" value="delete" />
        <br/>
        <label for="artistname'.$records['m_id'].'" id="artistLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Artist Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="30" name="artistname" class="artistname1" id ="artistname'.$records['m_id'].'" value="'.$records['artistname'].'" />
        <br/>
        <label for="recordname'.$records['m_id'].'" id="recordnameLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Record Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="30" name="recordname" class="recordname1" id ="recordname'.$records['m_id'].'" value="'.$records['recordname'].'"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="recordtype'.$records['m_id'].'" id="recordtypeLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Record type:</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="recordtype" class="recordtype1" id ="recordtype'.$records['m_id'].'" value="'.$records['recordtype'].'"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="format'.$records['m_id'].'" id="formatLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Format:</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="format" class="format1" id ="format'.$records['m_id'].'" value="'.$records['format'].'"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="price'.$records['m_id'].'" id="priceLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Price:</label>
        <input type="text" size="10" name="price" class="price1" id ="price'.$records['m_id'].'" value="'.$records['price'].'"/>
        <br/><br/>
    ';
    $musicfiles=getmusicfiles($records['m_id']);
    for($j=0; $j<2; $j++)
    {
        $mus=mysql_fetch_assoc($musicfiles);
        if(file_exists($mus['musicpath']))
        {
            echo '<a href="'.$mus['musicpath'].'">'.$mus['musicname'].'</a><br/>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<label for="musicFile'.$records['m_id'].'" id="musicFileLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Music:</label> <input type="file" size="40" name="musicFile1" id="musicFile'.$records['m_id'].'"/><br/>';
        }
    }
    $pictures=getpictures($records['m_id']);
    for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)
    {
        $pics=mysql_fetch_assoc($pictures);
        if(file_exists($pics['picturepath']))
        {
            echo '<img src="'.$pics['picturepath'].'" width="150" height="150"><br/>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<label for="pictureFile'.$records['m_id'].'" id="pictureFileLabel'.$records['m_id'].'">Picture:</label><input type="file" size="40" name="pictureFile1" id="pictureFile'.$records['m_id'].'"/><br/>';
        }
    }
}

echo'<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="modfiymusicitem" id="modfiymusicitem" /> ';
if ($pagenumber == 1) {
    echo " FIRST PREV ";
}
else {
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenumber=1'>FIRST</a> ";
    $prevpage = $pagenumber-1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenumber=$prevpage'>PREV</a> ";
}
echo "(Page $pagenumber of $lastpage)";
if ($pagenumber == $lastpage) {
    echo " NEXT LAST ";
}
else {
    $nextpage = $pagenumber+1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenumber=$nextpage'>NEXT</a> ";
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenumber=$lastpage'>LAST</a> ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the form data to the next page manually. This, most important part, is always forgotten by tutorial writers.

You have to pass to other pages, not only the page number, but the whole form data.
I hope your form uses the GET method, as it should be, so, you have your data either in the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` as a string or the `$_GET` array. So, you can either do `regexp pagenumber` in the `QUERY_STRING`, or assemble another `QUERY_STRING` from the `$_GET` array, like this:

```
$_GET['pagenumber']=$nextpage;
$query_string=http_build_query($_GET);
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?$query_string'>NEXT</a> ";
```